# Gedit Zen Coding Plugin

Tags: gedit, emmet

I've tried multiple times to install the Zen Coding plugin for Gedit in Ubuntu 11.10. (I have all the latest updates installed.) I know I'm doing it correctly because I've done it on other installations with no problem but for some reason it doesn't even show up in the plugins list. Anyone else having this problem or know how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu 11.10 ships with Gedit 3, 11.04 had Gedit version 2. Plugins written for version 2 will (supposedly) **not** work with the newer version, as it uses GTK3, while Gedit2 used GTK2.
Some of the plugin changes are:

- New folder: `~/.local/share/gedit/plugins`
- `.gedit-plugin` extension should be named `.plugin`
- `[Gedit Plugin]` header should be `[Plugin]`
- `IAge=2` should be `IAge=3`
- All plugins must have a `.plugin` file along side it.

Here's [a blog post](http://www.micahcarrick.com/writing-plugins-for-gedit-3-in-python.html) I found that covers making plugins for Gedit 3. And here's a relevant question on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61785/how-do-i-install-a-plugin-for-gedit-v3).

Answer (score 12):

I found that for GEdit 3 this plugin works : https://github.com/mtrovo/zen-coding-gedit3.